# Writing the data to the input with jquery when I click the button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, .net

There is an update button for each person in the table. When I click this button, I want that person's data to be written to `@Html.DropDownListFor`.
The code i tried :

Button :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-update" data-id="@item.bakim_id" data-customer="@item.musteriAdSoyad" data-product="@item.urunAd" data-date="@item.alinanTarih" data-month="@item.ay">
    <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
</button>
```

DropDownLists :

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Repairs", "Repair", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "repairSuccess" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Repairs.bakim_id, new { id = "repair_id" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Repairs.crud_type, new { id = "crud_type" })

                <div class="mb-3"> 
                    <label for="repairCustomerInput" class="form-label">Müşteri</label>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m=> m.Repairs.musteriID, Model.CustomersList, "Lütfen Bir Müşteri Seçiniz", new {@class="form-control repair-inputs", id="repairCustomerInput", required="required"})
                </div>

                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="repairProductInput" class="form-label">Ürün</label>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Repairs.urunID, Model.ProductsList, "Lütfen Bir Ürün Seçiniz", new {@class="form-control repair-inputs", id="repairProductInput", required="required"})
                </div>

                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="repairDateInput" class="form-label">Satışın Veya Yapılan Son Bakımın Tarihi</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Repairs.alinanTarih, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { @class = "form-control repair-inputs", id = "repairDateInput", type = "date", required = "required" })
                </div>

                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="repairMonthInput" class="form-label">Aylık Süre</label>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Repairs.ay, new SelectList(new[]{
                     new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "3 Ay" },
                     new SelectListItem { Value = "6", Text = "6 Ay" },
                     new SelectListItem { Value = "9", Text = "9 Ay" },
                     new SelectListItem { Value = "12", Text = "12 Ay" }}, "Value", "Text"), "Lütfen bakımın kaç aylık olacağını seçiniz",
                     new { @class = "form-control repair-inputs", id = "repairMonthInput", required = "required" })
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Kaydet</button>
            }
```

Javascript :

```
function openModal(isUpdate) {
if (isUpdate) {
    modalTitle = "Bakım Güncelle";
    $("#crud_type").val("update");
} else {
    modalTitle = "Yeni Bakım Ekle";
    $("#crud_type").val("insert");
}
$('#insertUpdateModalLongTitle').text(modalTitle);
$('#insertUpdateModal').modal('show');
$(document).on('click', '.btn-new', function () {
openModal(false);
$(document).on('click', '.btn-update', function () {
openModal(true);
$("#repair_id").val($(this).data("id"));
$("#repairCustomerInput").val($(this).data("customer"));
$("#repairProductInput").val($(this).data("product"));
$("#repairDateInput").val($(this).data("date"));
$("#repairMonthInput").val($(this).data("month"));
```

DevTools :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-update" data-id="19" data-customer="Hasan Ali Caner KALDIRIM" data-product="asd" data-date="1.01.2023 00:00:00" data-month="0">
                    <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                </button>
```

I have tested that I can get the data correctly. However, the data is not selected when the modal is opened.

Comment: Do you specifically mean that `$("#repairProductInput").val($(this).data("product"));` isn't doing what you expect?  When you debug, what value does `$(this).data("product")` resolve to on this line of code?  Can you update this to a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, focusing on the client-side functionality being addressed rather than server-side code?

Comment: Please add the `openModal()` code and the HTML of the modal pop-up too.

Comment: @krautcez please share the final HTML of the modal pop-up rendered over the browser, not its code.

Comment: I updated my code if I understood the right thing.

Comment: try like this: `$('#insertUpdateModal').find("#repair_id").val($(this).data("id"));`  and so on for others

Comment: It didn't work. But the problem is that the "Please select a product" part, which I normally write as default, does not appear either. So something is right but the data is not selected.

Comment: I can get the data properly. Because I can get the id properly, the update process is successful. The problem is that that person's data is not selected.